# Google+ Local and Google+ Page

Tags: google-plus, google-local-search, google-places

Ok, I'm a bit confused by all of this, I have 2 main questions.

1. The company I work for has a Google Places account, now Google+ Local as I understand. Where I'm getting confused is, what is the difference between a Google+ Local page and a Google+ page?
2. In search results, there are a few competitors showing in the rankings with map markers to the right (not in the right hand side of the page) and under the web site name - Google+ page. The company I work for does better than these in the search results, but doesn't have a map marker or a link below to a Google+ page. Can anyone give me an idea how to get ranked like these other web sites?

I have only today created a Google+ account, and would like some advice before I go creating a page when there already exists a Google+ Local page. I read [here](http://www.steamfeed.com/why-you-must-merge-your-google-local-and-google-page-now/) that these 2 pages should be merged?

Comment: Please don't use link shorteners here.

Answer (score 1):

In my own experience:

A Google+ Page is part of Google's social network. Think Facebook Page for businesses. If a business with a Google+ Page also has a physical location, it can create and verify a Local (previously Places) Page which essentially merges as part of the business' profile

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2659170?hl=en) :

> When a business owner verifies a local Google+ Page, any existing
>   listing for the business is merged with the local Google+ Page to
>   create a single page with a verified checkmark. Verified local Google+
>   Pages have features of both pages described above–scores and reviews
>   as well as posts from the business owner.

[To verify a Local Google+ Page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2609871?rd=1), a postcard with a PIN is mailed to the physical address of the business. The PIN must be entered into the business' account by an expiration date or go through the process again.